# Why cannot cancel terms $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$ for both side of the equation, chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, computational-mathematics, chain-rule

Suppose I have a function $\rho(x(X,t),t)$, and I perform the partial derivative based on chain rule, what I have is
$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$.

I am confused, both side has$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative on the left side shouldn’t be written using partial derivatives; rather, it is the total derivative. The term on the right side is the partial derivative in $t$ viewing $x$ as fixed.

Comment: An important special case of $\frac{d\rho}{dt}=\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\cdots$ is found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)#Liouville_equations).

Comment: Thank you J,G, I see here, it is partial, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalDerivative.html

Answer (score 0):

The letter $\rho$ is being used to denote two different functions. Suppose that $R(u,t) = \rho(x(u,t),t)$. By the multivariable chain rule, $\frac{\partial R}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t}$. For some reason the function $R$ is often called $\rho$, even though the name $\rho$ has already been used for a different function. This is a common abuse of notation and it frequently causes confusion.

Comment: Thank you, which two functions that $\rho$ is denoting?